# Is there any product formula for local zeta function?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

Suppose that $V$ is a non-singular $n$-dimensional projective algebraic variety over the field $\mathbb{F}_q$ with $q$ elements.  The local zeta function $Z(V, s)$ of $V$ (sometimes called the congruent zeta function) is defined as

$${ Z(V,s)=\exp \left(\sum _{m=1}^{\infty }{\frac {N_{m}}{m}}(q^{-s})^{m}\right)} $$
where $N_m$ is the number of points of $V$ defined over the degree $m$ extension of $\mathbb{F}_q$.

Does $Z(V, s)$ have a product decomposition similar to Riemann Zeta function? Is it anyway connected to the Riemann Zeta function?

Comment: it is connected to one of the local factor $\frac{1}{1-p^{-s}} = 1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty p^{-sk}$ of $\zeta(s)$. Note that from $e^{x} = 1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$ you can write your $Z(V,s)$ as $1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty c_k q^{-ks}$

Comment: To see a connection to the Riemann zeta function you want to look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_zeta_function   These are global objects attached to an arithmetic scheme, and if you choose your scheme to be the $\text{Spec} \mathbf{Z}$, then it specializes to the usual Riemann zeta function.